# Material design lite prevents ng-click if navigator.standalone is true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, material-design-lite

I have this [demo app](http://kohlin.net/lab/angular)
It works as intended in mobile safari (and desktop) but when I add the page to homescreen I can no longer click (ng-click) the card heading to toggle class to show full contact card. Any idea why that only happens when in standalone mode? 
I have it as [a codepen here](http://codepen.io/jkohlin/pen/XmbeNp) as well

```
<head>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
</head>
<body>
<div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--blue-grey-500" ng-click="showCard($index)">
```